# Identity Server 4 - Unable to authenticate user

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid

I have the following client:

```
 new Client
 {
    RequirePkce = false,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    ClientId = "client_id_mobile",
    ClientSecrets =
    {
      new Secret("client_secret_mobile".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,                    
    },
    RedirectUris = new []
    {
      "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
    },
  }
```

I'm trying to authenticate a user by doing the following within postman:

[image]

But as you can see I get `unsupported_grant_type`, I've tried changing the grant type to `code` I then get `unauthorized_client`

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new development, you should only consider using the authorization code flow or the client credentials flow. All other flows is deprecated as of OAuth2.1.

If you want to login using a username/password and there is no user involved, then use the client credentials flow instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per OAuth2.1 specification, PKCE should be supported in Authorization code grant but many servers support Authorization grant as per OAuth2.0. You can try any 1 of them.